# Parse Error: syntax error in echo statement

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing a script that display a list of checkboxes containing data stored in my database: `email_list` table.

My script:

```
<img src="blankface.jpg" width="161" height="350" alt="" style="float:right" />
<img name="elvislogo" src="elvislogo.gif" width="229" height="32" border="0" alt="Make Me Elvis" />
<p>Please select the email addresses to delete from the email list and click Remove.</p> 

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> ">

<?php   
    $dbc= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'elvis_store')
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM email_list";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error querying database');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id']'" name="todelete[]" />';
        echo $row['firstname'];
        echo $row['lastname'];
        echo $row['email'];
        echo '<br />';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remove" />

</form>
```

While I'm running this script, it display a Parse error:

> **Parse error: syntax error**, unexpected ''" name="todelete[]" />'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\removeemail.php on line 16

I don't get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add . after `$row['id']`

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['id'] . '" name="todelete[]" />';
```

Comment: I didn't understand 100% why put single quotes in the value property? We already have single quotes in the echo.

Comment: if you will not use single quote to bind variable then it will break the entire input tag'

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `.` in your first echo statement. `.` must be at the both ends to concatenate the string.

Update your code like this.

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'. $row['id'].'" name="todelete[]" />';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand 100% why put single quotes in the value property? We already have single quotes in the echo.

Comment: That's because you want to concatenate the `PHP variable` with string. Look at the reference manual.